# How can I rearrange text file value programmatically

Tags: python, file

Problem statement:

```
Class    Confidence    Xmin   Ymin    Xmax  Ymax
9        0.9745781     45     8        39   49
6        0.9401682     1      1        79   52
3        0.0167890     34     7        90   45
```

This value will have in my file. I want to rearrange all data such as: I want to compare Xmin value. If Xmin value is small then Xmin line will write in the Top i mean ascending order.

Expected output:

```
Class    Confidence    Xmin   Ymin    Xmax  Ymax
6        0.9401682     1      1        79   52
3        0.0167890     34     7        90   45
9        0.9745781     45     8        39   49
```

How can I do this programmatically using python? All data have text file and after doing this I want to save value same format in text file.

Answer (score 0):

If `file.txt` contains:

```
Class    Confidence    Xmin   Ymin    Xmax  Ymax
9        0.9745781     45     8        39   49
6        0.9401682     1      1        79   52
3        0.0167890     34     7        90   45
```

Then running this script:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
    open('file_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(next(f_in))  # skip the header, write it directly to output file
    f_out.write('\n'.join(line.strip() for line in sorted(f_in, key=lambda k: int(k.split()[2]))))
```

will produce `file_out.txt`:

```
Class    Confidence    Xmin   Ymin    Xmax  Ymax
6        0.9401682     1      1        79   52
3        0.0167890     34     7        90   45
9        0.9745781     45     8        39   49
```

Comment: After run this script i dont get expected output that you mentioned (File_out.txt)

Comment: @EliasHossain Is your input file in `file.txt`? Did running the script end in error? What was the output?

Comment: My expected output is (file_out.txt) you mentioned already, But i did not get this after run this script. After run this script and new file will create cannot print processing data ..That print file.txt data

Comment: @EliasHossain I double checked it and this script will create `file_out.txt` when `file.txt` contains the data as mentioned in the question. Either your file `file.txt` is different or there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Bro. After run this script file_out.txt will make but print file.txt value. But my expected output is file_out.txt.  I didnot get this after run this script.